# In "Pacific Rim: Uprising", what is this object in the Jaeger simulator?

Tags: pacific-rim, pacific-rim-uprising

About halfway through *Pacific Rim: Uprising*, Jake Pentecost comes to see Amara Namani in a Jaeger simulator where she's training, and they attempt to drift together. Before that, we see that the simulator contains

> what appears to be a human brain, suspended in a small cylindrical tank, which Jake calls by name and expresses some familiarity with.

Presumably this is used to run Jaeger-piloting simulations with only one pilot, but is there any explanation for what this is and how it got there? I can think of a number of possibilities...

> - the brain of a deceased Jaeger pilot
>  - a cloned brain that was "born" in an artificial system and lives in VR
>  - a structural replication of a human brain that is not necessarily "alive"
>  - some sort of kaiju-brain derivative, which seems unlikely given the state of Dr. Geiszler

However, there's certainly no explanation offered in *Pacific Rim: Uprising*. I don't recall this technology being referred to in the first film, but was there actually an explanation there, or in the *Pacific Rim* comic books, or in any other supplementary materials?

Comment: As stated by Jake, the brain's name is "Sarah", which I hope was a reference to "cerebellum"...

Comment: My understanding of it was that they used the brain to train to drift with a more "passive" copilot. Since the theory of drifting with a dead brain had been experienced with success in the first movie, it seems like a logical next step

Comment: @MarathontoMay - fagh, of course there is a movie title with "brain" that starred a "sarah". Googs is too thorough sometimes.

Comment: The technology we see there was definitely new. From the first film the only way they could test for drift comparability was by having them fight hand to hand... to learn more we will have to wait for either novelization details or perhaps behind the scenes information.

Comment: I've reached out (via twitter and email) to the film's writers and producers. Hopefully we'll get an answer that way.

Answer (score 5):

The movie's [official junior novelisation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1683833864) and [official novelisation](https://pacificrim.fandom.com/wiki/Pacific_Rim:_The_Official_Movie_Novelization) both offer confirmation that it is indeed a human brain, but beyond that, there's not a lot more information on offer.

> He approached the drift rig Amara was punching. He saw that one side was occupied by **a human brain floating in a container of synthetic cerebral fluid. A plaque mounted below the brain read: THIS IS SARAH. SHE DONATED HER MIND SO THAT YOU COULD TRAIN.** TELL ME HER FAVORITE CANDY BAR.
>   Jake smiled. “They’re still using Sarah, huh?”

Comment: Wow! I wonder if that plaque was actually part of the film set, or invented by the author. It seems to make clear how the training was conducted, too - drifting without a combat simulation.

Comment: @recognizer - The plaque is mentioned in both novelisations. That being said, the junior novel is simply an expurgated version of the official novelisation

Comment: No Sarah was in PR novelization or prequel comic, so this is someone new for Uprising